# Problem in reading input from user and writing to a file in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, file-io, base-class

This is the base class Employee code

```java
public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String address;
    private String EmpId;
    private double salary;

    public Employee(String name,int age,String address,String EmpId,double salary)  {
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;
        this.address=address;
        this.EmpId=EmpId;
        this.salary=salary;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getEmpId() {
        return EmpId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(String empId) {
        EmpId = empId;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}
```

Here Software employee is extending this base class

```java
public class SoftwareEmployee extends Employee{
    private String skillSet;
    public SoftwareEmployee(String name,int age,String address,String EmpId,double salary,String 
    skillSet) {
        super(name,age,address,EmpId,salary);
        this.skillSet=skillSet;
    }

    public String getSkillSet() {
        return skillSet;
    }

    public void setSkillSet(String skillSet) {
        this.skillSet = skillSet;
    }

}
```

Also Finance Employee is extending the base class
the code is :

```java
public class FinanceEmployee extends Employee {
    private String Degree;
    public FinanceEmployee(String name,int age,String address,String EmpId,double salary,String Degree) {
        super(name,age,address,EmpId,salary);
        this.Degree=Degree;
    }

    public String getDegree() {
        return Degree;
    }

    public void setDegree(String degree) {
        Degree = degree;
    }   
}
```

Here it can't write to an external file. Also console is not waiting for me to insert name first and then age. It is just printing name and age at once and then again two things at the same time. I am very new to this.

This is my main class

```java
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //File file = new File("C:\\Users\\AK078479\\Documents\\newfile.txt");
        FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\AK078479\\Documents\\newfile.txt");
        //BufferedWriter writer = null;

        Employee employee=new Employee(null, 0, null, null, 0);
        SoftwareEmployee sftemp=new SoftwareEmployee(null, 0, null, null, 0, null);
        FinanceEmployee fncemp=new FinanceEmployee(null, 0, null, null, 0, null);
        System.out.println("You are "+"\n"+"1.Reviewer"+"\n"+"2.Data Entry Operator");
        int choice = sc.nextInt();
        switch(choice) {
            case(1): 
                System.out.println("Do you want to see a"+ "\n" + "1.Particular record"+"\n"+"2.All 
         records");
                int value=sc.nextInt();
                switch(value) {
                    case(1):
                }
                break;
            case(2):
                System.out.println("Employee is a "+"\n"+"1.Software Employee"+"\n"+"2.Finance 
      Employee");
                int num =sc.nextInt();
                switch(num) {
                    case(2):
                        try {

                            //String s="Finance Employee";
                            //writer.write(s);
                            //writer.newLine();
                            int n=2;
                            while(n>0) {

                                //writer = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
                                System.out.println("Enter name");
                                String text = sc.next();
                                fncemp.setName(text);
                                fWriter.write(text);
                                //fWriter.newLine();
                                System.out.println("Enter age");
                                int age=sc.nextInt();
                                fncemp.setAge(age);
                                fWriter.write(age);
                                //writer.newLine();
                                System.out.println("Enter address");
                                String add = sc.nextLine();
                                fncemp.setAddress(add);
                                fWriter.write(add);
                                //fwriter.newLine();
                                System.out.println("Enter EmpId");
                                String emplId = sc.nextLine();
                                fncemp.setEmpId(emplId);
                                fWriter.write(emplId);
                                //writer.newLine();
                                System.out.println("Enter salary");
                                double sal = sc.nextDouble();
                                fncemp.setSalary(sal);
                                fWriter.write((int) sal);
                                //writer.newLine();
                                System.out.println("Enter degree");
                                String degree = sc.nextLine();
                                fncemp.setDegree(degree);
                                fWriter.write(degree);
                                //writer.newLine();  
                                n--;
                            }      
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("Error!");
                        }
                    break;
                    case(1):
                        try {

                            //String st="Software Employee";
                            //writer.write(st);
                           // writer.newLine();
                            int n=2;
                            while(n>0) {

                                //fWriter = new FileWriter(file);
                                //writer = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
                                System.out.println("Enter name");
                                //String text = sc.nextLine();
                                sftemp.setName(sc.nextLine());
                                fWriter.write(sftemp.getName());
                                //fWriter.newLine();
                                System.out.println("Enter age");
                                int age=sc.nextInt();
                                sftemp.setAge(age);
                                fWriter.write(age);
                                //fWriter.newLine();
                                System.out.println("Enter address");
                                String add = sc.nextLine();
                                sftemp.setAddress(add);
                                fWriter.write(add);
                                //writer.newLine();
                                System.out.println("Enter EmpId");
                                String emplId = sc.nextLine();
                                sftemp.setEmpId(emplId);
                                fWriter.write(emplId);
                                //writer.newLine();
                                System.out.println("Enter salary");
                                double sal = sc.nextDouble();
                                sftemp.setSalary(sal);
                                fWriter.write((int) sal);
                                //writer.newLine();
                                System.out.println("Enter skill Set");
                                String skill = sc.nextLine();
                                sftemp.setSkillSet(skill);
                                fWriter.write(skill);
                                //writer.newLine();  
                                n--;
                            }      
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("Error!");
                        }
                    break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Try again");

                }
                break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Try again");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you use a scanner method `nextInt()` you should call `nextLine()` one more time before you can read a string. The reason for that is that after you call `nextInt` the scanner internal cursor which tracks your position in the input stream passes the integer number, but stops right in front of the new line character. When you call `nextLine()` the scanner will just return the empty string and move to the next line, so only the next `nextLine()` call will return non-empty string which you entered after the number. Thus, for example here:

```java
System.out.println("You are "+"\n"+"1.Reviewer"+"\n"+"2.Data Entry Operator");
int choice = sc.nextInt();
switch(choice)
```

you need to add:

```java
System.out.println("You are "+"\n"+"1.Reviewer"+"\n"+"2.Data Entry Operator");
int choice = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();   // Skip the end of line and prepare to read something from the next line
switch(choice)
```